# Submit dynamically generated form to laravel not working

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a form that is generated into a uikit modal when a row in a table is clicked. 
The modal is populated by jquery after an ajax call, all of which is working fine. But when I try to submit the form Im getting some escaping in the url that is breaking the routing. 
//form code

```
<form class='uk-grid-small uk-form-horizontal' uk-grid 
action='{{action('customerController@editCustomer')}}' method='post'>
```

//routing

```
Route::post('/editCustomer', 'customerController@editCustomer');
```

//what is showing in the browser
http://dev.bindle/%7B%7Baction(

So Im assuming that the {{}} in the action is being escaped, but I cant figure out where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it help if you change the route to

`Route::post('/editCustomer', 'customerController@editCustomer')->name('edit-customer');`

and then in the form to

`<form class='uk-grid-small uk-form-horizontal' uk-grid 
action='{{route('edit-customer')}}' method='post'>`

If this doesn't help I'd suggest to check also the app.url config.

Comment: Ive just tried those and got the same results, Ill take a look at the config next. Thank you :)